# Button does not appear in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
var go_top = $('.go-top');
function btn_go_top() {
    if (go_top.length) {
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(),
                go_top_height = go_top.outerWidth(),
                footer = $('.footer'),
                nav = $('.nav'),
                nav_top = nav.offset().top,
                nav_height = nav.height(),
                f_height = footer.height(),
                w_height = $(window).height(),
                f_top = footer.offset().top,
                go_top_margin = go_top_height + 40,
                popravka = (w_height - go_top_margin)/2;
        if (scroll_top > (nav_top + nav_height)) {
            go_top.css('margin-bottom', -go_top_height/2);
            go_top.fadeIn();
        }
        else{
            go_top.fadeOut();
        };
        if ((scroll_top + go_top_margin + popravka) > f_top) {
            go_top.css({'position': 'absolute', 'bottom': f_height + go_top_margin/2});
        }
        else {
            go_top.css({'position': 'fixed', 'bottom': '50%'});
        };
    };
}
```

Html tag with button is.
Tag with a button there, but the button is not visible when scrolling error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.dispatch
elemData.handle
Where implemented error and how to fix it? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: can you share a jsbin?\

Comment: go to jsbin.com.. and you can create a fiddle with the html,js you are using

Comment: You call `.top` on `nav.offset()` and `footer.offset()`. Perhaps those are undefined (or one of them), judging from your error. Have you tried to debug this at all?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not debugged.